# My app stop working after my certificate was renewed

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have an app in the markets that was working fine until my root certificate was renewed. Now I don't know how to procede... the certificate was in AWS and if I run the app in my computer, works fine, but in my phone is not working. I sniffed the traffic and the error that I got is "User certificate is untrusted"

Someone had the same problem?

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `Exception Domains` to `Info.plist`

iOS doesn't allow untrusted certificates if you don't add them to Info.plist.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's added. The problem just appeared when AWS automatically renewed my certificate. Do I should something like generate new rsa o something like that?

Comment: I don't have such experience. Try to clear cache with 
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
Try to look at SSL Pinning.